# How to extract vertical and horizontal lines from the image

Tags: python, opencv

**Task:**

I have a set of images where every image looks like this:

[image]

I'd like to extract all horizontal and all vertical lines from this image.

**Desired results:**

[image]

[image]

**Current approach:**

```
import cv2


image = cv2.imread('img.png')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (3, 3), 0)
thresh = cv2.threshold(blur, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

horizontal_kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (20, 1))
horizontal = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, horizontal_kernel, iterations=1)
```

Here's the result:

[image]

**Problem:**

It's clear that the current kernel is too narrow to bypass this thick vertical line on the left. This line is 41-pixel thick, so the kernel (42, 1) works fine, but I lose true horizontal lines that a shorter than 41 pixel:

[image]

Are there any flawless techniques for solving this problem?

Comment: you should define more clearly what you mean by "vertical line", you could argue everything is a vertical line. Right now you're simply extracting rows of white pixels that are longer than x pixels.

Comment: @Nearoo take a look at "Desired results" section, please. Yes, I need to extract all segments that're taller than square (vertical) and all segments that're wider than square (horizontal).

Comment: I can see your example, but and example is not enough. Before you start coding an algorithm, you have to know what you're trying to solve, just "my heart tells me that in this concrete example it should look like this" won't cut it. How do you divide your image in squares?

Answer (score 0):

The idea is to bring all those lines to the same "Size" by Skeletonization before
applying a morphological filter & use a smaller filter Size

```
image = cv2.imread('Your_ImagePath' , cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

thresh = skeletonize(thresh)
cv2.imshow("Skelton",thresh)
cv2.waitKey()

horizontal_kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (10, 1))
horizontal = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, horizontal_kernel, 
iterations=1)

cv2.imshow("Horizontal Lines" , horizontal)
v2.waitKey()
```

OUTPUT IMAGE :

[image]

NOTE : Skeletonization code from [skeletonize.py](https://gist.github.com/jsheedy/3913ab49d344fac4d02bcc887ba4277d)

Comment: But you're losing actual sizes of the lines. For example, instead of one single line on the bottom you have three (and their total width is smaller that the width of original horizontal segment).

Answer (score 0):

I would be thinking about doing a *"Morphological Opening"* with a tall, thin structuring element (i.e. a vertical line 15 pixels tall and 1 pixel wide) to find the vertical bars and with a horizontal line 15 pixels long and 1 pixel high to find the horizontal bars.

You can do it just the same with **OpenCV**. but I am just doing it here with **ImageMagick** in the Terminal because I am quicker at that! Here's a command for the vertical work - try varying the 15 to get different results:

```
magick shapes.png -morphology open rectangle:1x15 result.png
```

Here's an animation of how the result changes as you vary the 15 (the length of the line):

[image]

And here is how it looks when you make the structuring element a horizontal line:

```
magick shapes.png -morphology open rectangle:15x1 result.png
```

[image]

If you are new to morphology, there is an excellent description by Anthony Thyssen [here](https://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/morphology/). Note that it may be explained in terms of **ImageMagick** but the principles are equally applicable in Python **OpenCV** - see [here](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d9/d61/tutorial_py_morphological_ops.html).