# Join broken lines in image using OpenCV for python

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, scikit-image

I am working on a project in which I have to complete the broken lines in the image below and then calculate the area. Is there any way to complete the broken lines in the image below using python?

[image: Image with broken lines]

Comment: Did you tried something?

Comment: I tried to obtain the skeleton of the image and then join the lines but it does not work so well and also discards the thickness of the lines

Comment: Add some code that you use to your post.

Comment: This shoukd give you an idea... https://stackoverflow.com/a/63414618/2836621

Comment: could you please also upload the expected result? I did not get it completely in which lines should be merged and which not.

Comment: To connect broken lines/edges based on contour extremities have a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71811385/connecting-disjointed-lines-or-edges-in-binary-images/71816288#71816288

Answer (score 3):

Do you mean something like this?

[image: result image]

This can be done with simple morphology; however, it is subject to two conditions:

1. You only have horizontal and vertical lines
2. The gaps you want to fill are strictly smaller than gaps you want to preserve (empty space in the image)

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as numpy

from skimage import io
from skimage import morphology

img = io.imread("test.png", as_gray=True)

# fill horizontal gaps
selem_horizontal = morphology.rectangle(1,50)
img_filtered = morphology.closing(img, selem_horizontal)

# fill vertical gaps
selem_vertical = morphology.rectangle(80,1)
img_filtered = morphology.closing(img_filtered, selem_vertical)

plt.imshow(img_filtered, cmap="gray")
plt.gca().axis("off")
plt.show()
```